# Firebase Microsoft SignInWithCredential

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, azure-authentication

I am setting up Microsoft authentication in Firebase (web js sdk), but I'm running into an error with `firebase.auth.signInWithCredential`. I can successfully get an id token from Microsoft, but the Firebase auth step fails. I've tried Firebase v8 and v9, and various ways of forming my credential object. In fact, I get the same error even passing an access token. There seems to be something wrong with the Firebase library.
Has anyone experienced this issue before and resolved it?

Code:

```
const { id_token } = authResponse.params; // I've verified that id_token is correct
const credential = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider("microsoft.com").credential({
  idToken: id_token,
  rawNonce: "12345",
});
await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
```

The credential seems to be generated fine:

```
Object {
  "accessToken": undefined,
  "idToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV...",
  "nonce": "12345",
  "pendingToken": null,
  "providerId": "microsoft.com",
  "secret": undefined,
  "signInMethod": "microsoft.com",
}
```

But the `signInWithCredential` step gets the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) 
code: "auth/internal-error"
message: "Invalid IdP response/credential: http://localhost?id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV..."
```

Comment: Did someone found solution to this? Implementing and managing `signInWithCustomToken` just for Microsoft on native app seems like hell that you don't want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `signInWithCredential` isn't supported for Microsoft OAuth. https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/microsoft
I will try doing `signInWithCustomToken` for existing users and give a warning for new users to sign up first on web, where I will do `signInWithPopup`

Comment: did you find a way to get this running? Would love to see the solution!

Comment: It is insane that microsoft is not supported....

Comment: yeah it's too bad that signInWithCredential is not supported for Microsoft.  would make life so much easier.  Guess i am also going to do `signInWithCustomToken` here.

Comment: Did someone found solution to this? Implementing and managing `signInWithCustomToken` just for Microsoft on native app seems like hell that you don't want to do.